# How to match a pattern with a hyphen or apostrophe

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regular expression to accept a name if it includes a-z A-Z but also some names may include a hyphen or apostrophe. I have this so far and its doesn't match anything:

```
(^[a-zA-Z]['][-]$)
```

Comment: Take a look at [Character escaping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character).

Comment: You need to add quantifiers and an optional group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex `^[a-zA-Z]['][-]$` matches a letter followed with `'` and `-`. Something like `a'-`.

You need to add quantifiers and an optional group (`*` will allow 0 or more occurrences), e.g.

```
^[a-zA-Z]+(?:['-][a-zA-Z]+)*$
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rZ3bQ5/2)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/SckBrOLGFJaCUCPa)

The pattern anchors the whole match (it should match the whole string) and it matches 1 or more letters (`[a-zA-Z]+`) and then *0 or more occurrences*  of a `'` or `-` (thanks to `['-]`) followed by 1+ letters.

Comment: This works but only if there is a ' or -, I probably should have been more clear sorry. I am trying to allow them to enter a name with either only characters of upper and lower, and if need be a ' or - or even both.

Comment: Then use `^[a-zA-Z]+(?:['-][a-zA-Z]+)*$` - this will allow many `'` and `-`, but not consecutively (i.e. `--` and `''` are not allowed). I modified the answer (regex and demo) to reflect this specific requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead:

```
^[a-zA-Z'-]+$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dZ6cO3/1)

[image: Visualization]

Comment: Well, this will match `----''''` strings.

Comment: You are right, but it's hard to know what OP wants without him providing test cases and/or a clear description of what should be matched. I just corrected it to something which is close to his solution, because I thought this might be what he wanted

Answer (score 0):

```
first_name = input("Enter first name: ")
try:
    if not re.search("^[A-Za-z'- ]+$", first_name):
        raise ValueError:
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid first name, must use letters or acceptable name symbols")
else:
    break
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?